# AJAX request failing to retrive xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I am trying to call a GET on https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/hot.xml.  I receive an alert saying that the request went through.   The problem is when I did a simple parse on it and outputted the result in an alert, the HTML code of the page is shown instead.  Now I'm not sure if I'm receiving the right data in the first place now. Am I calling the AJAX incorrectly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="tasklist.js"> </script>-->
<script>
 /*   $(document).ready(function(){
    Listing();
});*/


(function($){Listing=function(){        
 $.ajax({   
URL:'https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/hot.xml',
dataType:"xml",

type: "GET",
success: function (data) {    
    alert(data);
    var xmlDoc= new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data);

    alert(xmlDoc.toString());
},
error: function (data) { alert(0) }  
})
}})(jQuery);



</script>
</head>

<body>
<script>Listing();</script>
<div id="List"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your url argument is incorrect. It has to be all lowercase ('url').
Even if you fix that, it will not work, since you are making a cross domain request. Read about that here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

One feasible way is to have your own server make a call to reddit and send back the data to browser. It may also be possible to load that xml in an iframe and get access to that document, but I'm not sure it would work.

Comment: Why is it I don't see the cross domain request problem when I request for a JSON file instead? (I'm trying to practice with XML file requests)

Comment: What JSON file did you request? If it was on your own server, you will not experience cross domain issues.